# using getElementByClassName in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this code to get product name from a page
code of page is

```
<div class="product-shop col-sm-7">
<div class="product-name">
<h1 >Claro Glass 1.5 L Rectangular Air Tight Food Container with Lid- Clear GMA0215A</h1>
</div>
```

my vba code is

```
Public Sub GetValueFromBrowser()
Dim ie As Object
Dim name As String
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "RUNNING"
URL = Selection.Value
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
.Visible = 0
.navigate URL
While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend
End With
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = ie.document
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "ERROR"
name = Trim(Doc.getElementByClassName("product-name").innerText)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = name
ie.Quit
Loop
End Sub
```

error i am getting is

> run-time error '438':
>
> Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Please, add a comment to the code, where the error occurs. I gues it is on the `name = Trim(Doc.getElementByClassName("product-name").innerText)`, there is a missing `s` in `getElementsByClassName`. Since this returns a collection, you will then have to specify an item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### GetElementsByClassName method

You are missing an `s` in the name of the method getElement**s**ByClassName.

- Change this `name = Trim(Doc.getElementByClassName("product-name").innerText)`
- To this `name = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("product-name")(0).innerText)`. Substitude the `(0)` for the item you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

It is still possible to define your own function `getElementByClassName`.

This function returns the *very first element* with given class name in the DOM document and *Nothing* when no element with this class name exist in the DOM document.

```
Public Function getElementByClassName(doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, className As String) As IHTMLElement
    Set getElementByClassName = doc.querySelector("[class='" & className & "']")
End Function
```

*Usage:*

```
Dim elm As IHTMLElement
Set elm = getElementByClassName(doc, "product-name")

If Not elm Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print elm.innerText
End If
```