# website no_id yes_class getelement then click

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

Based on the website's id I have been using

```
myIE.Document.getElementById("IDname1").Value = mystring1
```

And then

```
myIE.Document.getElementById("IDname2").Click
```

However using a different website I do not have an id for `IDname1`, only a class `"CLASSname1"`

I do have `IDname2`, but to CLICK I first need to enter the string

I looked into some posts like this one but still running into error
[using getElementByClassName in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328237/using-getelementbyclassname-in-vba)

Comment: what is the url? where is the relevant html? And what is the error you are getting using classname? myIE.document.getElementsByClassName("CLASSname1")(addIndexHere). value = ''xyz"

Comment: Thanks. I need to insert the mystring1 in a search box of the search engine. The search box has no id, only class.


Once the string is inserted I can do myIE.Document.getElementById("IDname2").Click   and it works, but to do this I first need to insert the string.

I followed your suggestion, using (0) it doesn't insert the string, doing (1) shows error 91 Object variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: can you share the URL ?

Comment: it is proquest, a log in required search engine

Comment: can you share the html for the page using https://pastebin.com/ ? You can also use [edit] to insert the html for the relevant element using the snippet tool. I assume by login you mean you must have a login to get to the page in question?

Comment: i just replaced value with innertext and works, thanks though

Comment: Cool. Glad you got there